# Linear Gradient in CSS doesnt repeat vertically

Tags: css, gradient

I am having trouble having my background linear gradient repeat past the end of my content area. I have tried repeat-y and repeat and I don't know what else to do.
Here is a preview of what the output looks like: http://jsfiddle.net/derbyshirehayes/ZhsQH/

HTML Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>hiii582</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="gradient_background">``
    <div id="wrap">
    <div id="padding1"></div>
    <div id="header">
        <img src="images/header.png"/>
    </div>
    <div id="padding1"></div>
    <div id="navigation_bar">
        <img src="images/navigation_bar.png"/>
    </div>
    <div id="padding"></div>
    <div id="content_area">
        <img src="images/content_area.png"/>
    </div>
    <div id="padding"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS Code:

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}  

#wrap {
    width: 960px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#gradient_background {
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #8c9bb2 0%, #5b8fdf 100%);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}

#header {
    width: 900px;
    height: 100px;
    background-image: url('images/header.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}

#navigation_bar {
    width: 901px;
    height: 36px;
    background-image: url('images/navigation_bar.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
/* Padding between navigation bar and content */
#padding {
    padding: 10px;
}

#padding1 {
    padding: 5px;
}
#content_area {
    width: 899px;
    height: 404px;
    background-image: url('images/content_area.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

}
```

Comment: Your question is a little but confusing... Do you want your gradient to be applied only to #content_area ?

Comment: no, i want it to be applied to the background of my website.but it only goes down until it reaches the content area

Answer (score 0):

You need to give to your html 100% height:

```
html{
  height: 100%;
}
```

Because body looks at the height of it's parent (html)
You could take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZhsQH/4/). I painted all the divs with different colors so you could better distinguish between them